# Google Analytics: Avoiding Dupe E-Commerce Transactions in Multiple Visits to Thank-You

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, tracking

I'm trying to set up e-commerce tracking by adding `addTransaction` and `addItem` snippets to the thank-you page. The app design allows registered users to access the thank you page after their purchase has been made (view details link in My Orders). Would each additional visit to the thank-you page record a new item and and transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, for Enhanced Ecommerce, if multiple transactions occur with the exact same transaction information within the same session, regardless of whether they have the same product data or not, only the first transaction and product(s) will be recorded into GA. The rest are discarded.

If multiple transactions occur with the exact same transaction information across different sessions, they will all be counted. All the different product details will be aggregated under the common transaction ID in the GA reports.